# If g∘f is Onto and g is Onto, Can f Ever Not Be Onto?

Tags: functions, logic

Let $f: A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$ be functions, $g∘f$ be onto, and $g$ be onto. Does it follow that $f$ is necessarily onto? Give either a proof or counterexample.

**Work So Far**

If g is onto, then there is at least one $b∈B$ for every $c∈C$. However, the next portion, $g∘f$, is re-written as $g(f(x))$, which is also onto. I don't understand what statement I can make with that information given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A = \{a\}, B = \{b,c\}, C = \{d\}$.

Can you construct the functions and check whether or not they are onto?

Comment: Ah, I think I follow. So using $\{a\} \to f \to \{b,c\} \to g \to \{d\}$ I can show that $g(b)=g(c)=d$, and $g(f(a))$ is valid for $f(a) = b$ OR $f(a) = c$, but not both as it would no longer be a function. Therefore there can't be an element in A for every element in B and $f: A \to B $ can't be onto. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Surjections_as_right_invertible_functions). 
Or you can see this image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find a way to set up everything so that
$$A=C$$
and it is a proper subset of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $gf$ is $\{x\in A: f(x)\in dom g\}.$ If $g:B\to C$ is onto, then $gf:(dom gf)\to C$ is onto if $\{g(f(x)): x\in A\}=\{g(y):y\in B\}.$ This does not require that $f:A\to B$ is onto. For example if $A=B=\{0,1\}, C=\{0\},$ and $f(0)=f(1)=g(0)=g(1)=0$ then $g$ and $gf$ are onto but $f$ is not.